# How would I reference the last item of an array?

Tags: c#, game-development

I am making a game where there is a shop and an inventory. (both are arrays) When I add an item to the inventory, I extend the inventory by the length of the inventory by one. (`inv = invLength++`) However, when I try to use the same variable as a reference to add the bought item (`inv[invLength] = boughtItem`) it returns the error:

```
Stack Trace:

[System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   at Program.generalStore() :line 99
   at Program.askLoc() :line 240
   at Program.intro() :line 271
   at Program.Main() :line 276
```

Comment: Just use a `List<int>` with the Add method. When you declare Arrays they have a fixed length. Its easier to use List than redimension an Array.

Comment: Side note: for future questions re-read [mre] guidance on posting code - there is no way to know why exactly you are getting this error without seeing the code.

Comment: Array index ranges from 0 ~ (array.length - 1). index of last item = array.length - 1. If the array is created dynamically, the index should be -1.